# I have a class with a variable called available and other isActive

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting in django. I have a class with a variable called `available = models.CharField(max_length=20)` and other `isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)`. By default the variable available gets the value "available". I'd like to be able to get the word "unavailable" in the `available` field if `isActive` is `False`. thanks

```
def availibility (request, id): 
  listingData = Listing.objects.get(pk=id) 
  if listingData.isActive == False: 
  listingData.available = "unavailable" 
  listingData.save() return 
  render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listingData = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)    
if listingData.isActive == False:
    listingData.available = "unavailable"
    listingData.save()
```

Comment: hi, the complete code I tried was                                                                                           
 def availibility (request, id):
    listingData = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)    
    if listingData.isActive == False:
        listingData.available = "unavailable"
        listingData.save()
        return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html") but I haven't succeded

Comment: If available is always based on isActive, you would better use a model @property.